# Weather Logging Software on Windows Home Server

Tags: windows-home-server, weather

I'm looking for some weather logging software that I can run as a Windows Home Server add-in, or as a service on my Home Server, so I don't need to log into my Home Server to log weather data.

I have an Oregon Scientific WMR918 weather station, and an HP MediaSmart EX485 Windows Home Server. The two are currently connected through a serial bluetooth adapter, but that shouldn't matter as the computer sees it basically as a serial device.

I'm currently using Cumulus to log data and upload to Weather Underground, but it is a regular windows application, so I need to remain logged into my Home Server by RDP in order to run the software (I disconnect, but don't log off so the session remains open).

Ideally I would like something to run as a service or WHS add-in, so that it runs all the time without logging in, can log data from my WMR918, and can upload to Weather Underground.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you talking about this cumuls software ? http://sandaysoft.com/products/cumulus

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by creating a scheduled task, set it to run on boot under your user name and set the settings so that it doesn't need you to be logged in.